# select from 2 tables with multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I asked this with succes and im using this sql command

```
SELECT u . id, jmeno, email 
FROM friends f INNER JOIN login u ON f.idfriend = u.id 
WHERE f.iduser  =44 AND u.online =1


Friends :
id         iduser     idfriend
0             44            56
1             44            102
2             10            66
3             10            85
4             44            10
5             56            44 

Users:
id         name            email                   isonline
44         john          john@gmail.com                   1
10         joe           joe@yahoo.com                    1
185        mark          mark@so.com                      0
```

and i get all friends of iduser 44 but i also want to get friends from idfriend reverse.
like there is idfriend 44 and id user 56 i want also select the idfriend 44

what i mean i dont want have multiple records to one relations, i want it both ways 
like

Friends

```
   1      44      52
   2      52      44
```

and i want just 
       `1      44      52`     both way select

Comment: What you mean by "*i get all friends of iduser 44 but i also want to get friends from idfriend reverse. like there is idfriend 44 and id user 56 i want also select the idfriend 44*"?? Are you after `(f.iduser  =44 or f.idfriend=44)` ??

Comment: i got a friends relations like this
1             44            62
2             62            44
but i want only 
1             44            62

Comment: So why don't you filter by those ids then?

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when me.id = 44 then l2.Id else l1.Id end FriendId,
       case when me.Id = 44 then l2.email else l1.email end FriendEmail
from friends me
inner join login l1 on l1.id = me.friendId
inner join login l2 on l2.id = me.Id
where ((me.id = 44 and l1.online = -1)
    or (me.friendId = 44 and l2.online = -1))
```

Not pretty but should work. Not sure about the online logic, but I'm sure you can fix that if you need to.